# How to open chrome and display as texture in game c# / unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok, so my client wants a feature where the person should be able to find an image through google during their game. I'm not sure, the only idea I've had would be to basically screen record the specific application then apply it as a texture to a cube. It is also in **VR** so the **Chrome** searching has to be done specifically in application. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you could do a screen capture kind of thing - 
 i stumbled upon a video when i was trying to get some embeded browser functionality going:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMLSACaaOjU

as the above shows you could take a capture based off of a certain click then whatever texture coding would come after that capture

also on the asset store there are assets which are costly that already contain embedded web browser depending on the platform.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/embedded-browser-55459

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/3d-webview-for-android-137030

aside from that you would have to program the results returned from the google web search request made (unitywebrequest) and allow your client to select the image